# How to use Postgres sequences with Sequel?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I can't find anything in the docs, Postgres or otherwise, all references to sequences are about primary key sequences, so I'm at loss how to continue, or if it's even supported.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using `DB.run` and `DB.fetch` to do this with raw SQL.

According to "[Using raw SQL](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html#label-Using+raw+SQL)" in the cheatsheet use:

```
DB.run('CREATE SEQUENCE some_seq START 20000;')
```

and then in code:

```
def self.get_next_some_seq
  DB.fetch("select nextval('some_seq')").first[:nextval]
end
```

Comment: DB.run to create the sequence is fine.  For selecting next values, you could also use: `DB.get{nextval('some_seq')}`